# replace working for only first sub element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't want to use split or join.

```
var str = "cause variety of files";  
alert(str.replace(" " , "_"));
```

The code above outputs : `"cause_variety of files"`

The output I seek is : `"cause_variety_of_files"`

Comment: @JoaoPalma - you are right. i asked without using split and join read the question first

Comment: the solution with the regular expression is there too, if you see the answer with most upvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code :

```
str.replace(/ /g, "_");
```

By default, the `replace` function replace the first occurence. So you must use a RegExp with the `global` flag.

You can learn more on regulars expressions here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: "You must use regex" surely doesn't explain what the regex does. You should explain more.

Comment: Can you explain how it works?

Comment: I just edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this for multiple space

```
str.replace(/\s+/g,'_');
```

or single space

```
str.replace(/\s/g,'_');
```

Comment: `Try this` does not teach the asker anything. Please explain what you did and why it should work, otherwise it's not a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expression and the `replace()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elem = "cause variety of files";
    console.log(elem.replace(/\s+/g, '_'));
});
```

The regex takes all the whitespace ( 1 or more ) using the \s+ pattern and replace it by a string you like.
In your case a underscore.

Comment: You shouldn't use `alert()` like a debug statement. `console.log()` should be used for debugging (also because you can use breakpoints in dev tools if you need to pause execution). Also please explain what your regex does